# knockout - computed observable input is not being updated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a dynamic list of items (observableArray) and want to edit one at a time. After binding input field value to computed it seems to work but only the first time. Further changes to selected element doesn't update the input field.
Here's the code:

```
<DOCCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="knockout-3.1.0.debug.js"></script>
<style>
.active { background: #EE0; }
</style>
</head><body>
<table><thead><tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Element ID</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: elements">
  <tr data-bind="css: { active: ((sel() ? sel().id:'') === id) }, click: selectElement">
  <td data-bind="text: $index"></td>
  <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<button data-bind="click: createNew">New element</button>
<h2>Edit current selection</h2>
<label>Color</label><input type="text" data-bind="enable: sel() !== null, value: editColor">
<script>
var elements = ko.observableArray();
var sel = ko.observable(null); // currently selected element

var editColor = ko.computed({
  read: function(){
    if (!sel()) return '-null-'; // !!! here I'm expecting that due to fact I'm using this observable element inside this computable will be re-eavlued whenever I change sel element and therefore input field will be updated as well
    return sel().color;
  },
  write: function(val){
    sel().color = val;
    $('#' + sel().id).css('background-color', val);
  }
});

function selectElement(el){
    sel(el);
}

function createNew(){
  var id = 'id_' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000); // kinda uniq
  var newElement = {
    id: id,
    color: ''
  };

  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.setAttribute('id', id);

  newElement.dom = d;

  $(d).css('width', '100')
 .css('height', '100')
 .css('border', '1px solid #000');

  document.body.appendChild(newElement.dom);

  elements.push(newElement);
  sel(newElement); // here I'm requesting input value to change
}

$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(window);
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1) click "new" - notice that input field value has changed from -null- to empty string as one would expect. That is read

2) enter some value in text field like #ABC - value is being properly changed

3) hit "new" again - now value in input box should be changed due to fact that el() is now pointing to my new element. Why doesn't it happen?

My question is - I'm changing sel() to new value which is a dependency in read computed function. Why does it work only once?
Is there any better approach for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is clicking on the New element button, the currently selected element remains unchanged. Adding the following line function fixed the issue(Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a4Cwu/). This is just a copy paste of your code. No HTML/JS/CSS is split across). But still you could have implemented the entire page better.(just saying)

```
function createNew(){
    sel(null);
  var id = 'id_' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000); // kinda uniq
  var newElement = {
    id: id,
    color: ''
  };
```

Comment: Thanks. But I already have sel as last statement in createNew function. Why do I have to switch it back to null each time? Your solution looks to me more like work-around.